# Application life cycle iOS

Tags: ios

I having a problem with the application life in iOS programming. My application has the view controller that has been subclassed for drawing. Everything went fine till I decide that went the app go inactive (Press Home). I want it to load a new screen. I used notifications of `applicationWillEnterForeground` and a few others. What happens the drawing code fails when I try to get the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`, it comes back as nil. I assume I am attempting to get the context before it is available. What is the proper event. I think I tried all but the right one.

Comment: Where are you accessing `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`?   Can we see some context (no pun intended) - i.e. surrounding code?

Comment: Here is a snippet of the code. This code works fine during normal operation. When I tried to call it when coming active it errors 
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext.

    NSString *imgNamed;
    imgNamed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d.png" (int)letterNum];
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgNamed];
    CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextDrawImage(_context, CGRectMake(-700, 100, 400, 400), myImage.CGImage);

Comment: Your question implies that you are drawing in a view controller subclass.  Perhaps I misunderstood your description; but that it probably unwise and may be the source of the difficulties you are having.  Better subclass `UIView` and get your graphics context inside of `drawRect:`.  That way you're only accessing a context when there is a context to which to draw.

Comment: Thanks alot NSBum. I was by passing the drawRect: and I have no clue why I did that. The rest of the drawing was done that way. Thanks again.